# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy error message customization

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In Azure B2C, we are using custom policy for reset password userflow and we are trying to change the error message from 'This information is required' to 'Email address is required', 'Verification Code is required' etc etc.

To do this as per below link we need to call "UserMessageIfMissingRequiredElement" from our custom policy.

But I need some help from you to understand high level steps to overwrite display of "required_field" value to "UserMessageIfMissingRequiredElement".

I have followed below microsoft link to achieve this fuctionality but no success. hence need help from you to provide high level steps to achieve this fuctionality instead of providing any help document url in answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-example

Awaiting your answer thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-example

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfMissingRequiredElement">Missing required element: {0}</LocalizedString>
```

{0} will dynamically use the claim display name. So, the message will change based on claim name.

"error_requiredFieldMissing” can be used in addition.